# Difference between $(sel).html and dom.innerHTML

Tags: jquery, html, dom

With jQuery , I can use `$(sel).html(html)` to produce an html area.

Without jquery , I can do the same thing by `dom.innerHTML = html;`
I also found `$(sel).html()` is slower than `dom.innerHTML`, but why?

What's the differences between `$(sel).html` and `dom.innerHTML`?
Is it safe to use `dom.innerHTML` replace `$(sel).html`?

Comment: `$(sel).html()` needs [jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js) to be included.. :)

Comment: In [source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js), search for "html: function".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting the HTML with `.html()` provides some appropriate housekeeping to prevent memory leaks when using other jQuery features before it then sets `.innerHTML`.

For example, if you use `.data()` on an element and you assign `.innerHTML` of a parent of the object that you used `.data()` on, then `.html()` will clean up the `.data()` elements associated with the elements that are being replaced.  If you use `.innerHTML`, those `.data()` elements will be orphaned and never cleaned up until you leave the page (a short term memory leak).  The same is true of some jQuery data associated with event handlers on objects that are removed.

The safest way to program in jQuery is to use `.remove()` and `.html()` (or other similar jQuery functions) instead of native DOM functions when removing elements that you've used jQuery with.

`.html()` is likely slower because it is doing more (some of which is advantageous if using other jQuery features).

In reality, the memory leaks that might occur if you use `.innerHTML` directly on parents of elements that you've been using other jQuery features on are generally not an issue.  The places where they could be meaningful are if you have large data structures associated with an element (like in `.data()`) or if you create and destroy a large number of elements or if you intend for your page to run for a very long time (like a single page app).  So, if you want to be safe, you stick with jQuery methods for anything that can remove or replace an element.

Here's an example of a simple memory leak:

```
<div id="container"><span id="whatever">foo</span></div>
```

```
$("#whatever").data("somedata", "really long string");
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "<span>new text</span>";
```

This causes a leak of the `.data()` info set in that first line of code because jQuery never gets a chance to clean up the data associated with the #whatever object which has now been removed from the DOM, but jQuery never saw that you removed it.

Whereas, this does not leak in that way:

```
<div id="container"><span id="whatever">foo</span></div>
```

```
$("#whatever").data("somedata", "really long string");
$("#container").html("<span>new text</span>");
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery uses `.innerHTML` under the hood, so if you already have a DOM element, and you don't need [extra features](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) that `.html()` provides, then you can safely use `.innerHTML` directly.

Comment: Those "extra features" help you prevent memory leaks as a consequence of using other jQuery features like `.data()` or event handlers.  It's definitely safer to use `.html()` if you're using other jQuery features.

Answer (score 3):

as the Jquery Docs says about `.html()`

> This method **uses the browser's innerHTML property**. Some browsers may
>   not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original
>   document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the
>   quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric
>   characters.

I think it just become slower because .html() is a part of a bigger library of Jquery which let you do some more things. But between both methods using the .`innerHTML()` and `Jquery.html()` is ok

http://api.jquery.com/html/